# how to export an table/array in web to an csv/excel file in the same format it appears？

Tags: python, arrays, excel, csv

See the pics below：
[html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHBqe.)
[python output and code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXB5v.png)

The table/array format can be easily changed when export, is there any solution to keep the table/array format intact?

Part of the python code:

```
Content = driver.find_elements_by_id('data')
    for Table in Content:
        print(Table.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, read data in from the table. You can use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) or `string.split()` or some other method to separate `Table.text` into its component parts (e.g. a python dict or 2D list).

Then, you can use [python's `csv` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) to output that 2D list as a csv file, or you can look into [the several python libraries that interface with MS Excel](http://www.python-excel.org/) to output an Excel spreadsheet with that same data.